# Efficiently converting between MongoCursor and OrderedDict in Julia

Tags: mongodb, julia, ordereddictionary

I'm using [mongo.jl](https://github.com/Lytol/Mongo.jl) and need a more efficient way to convert between a `MongoCursor` and `OrderedDict`

Here, grabbing the data cursor with `find` typically takes < 1 second. Extracting and converting to OrderedDict takes ~20 seconds.

```
using Mongo
...
collection = MongoCollection(client, "myDB", json)
dataPre = find(collection, Dict(category=>id)) #Returns type Mongo.MongoCursor
i = 1
data = DataStructures.OrderedDict()
for rec in dataPre
    data[i] = dict(rec)
    i=i+1
end
```

---

Edit: I've realised through using `@profile` that 95% of my delay is in the conversion from dict to array, which is a few lines I omitted from the example code.

Here's the same example code with the omitted line:

```
using Mongo
...
collection = MongoCollection(client, "myDB", json)
dataPre = find(collection, Dict(category=>id)) #Returns type Mongo.MongoCursor
i = 1
data = DataStructures.OrderedDict()
form_arr = Array(Float64,(100,100,8,length(dataPre)))
for rec in dataPre
    data = dict(rec)                                                        #A
    for v1 = 1:100
         for v2 = 1:8
             form_arr[v1,:,v2,i] = data["info"][v1]["meas"][v2]["vals"]     #B
         end
    end
    i=i+1
end
```

The profiler indicates that line A takes ~ 5% of time, and line B uses up 95% of the time.

I'm stuck with that dict structure.. Is there a way to extract and format the data more efficiently?

Comment: A cursor is generally a virtual representation of the result. It is only when you iterate the cursor will the actual response be fetched from the server on to the client's memory. So the time you see may not be for converting to an OrderedDict, it may just be the time it takes for mongo to fetch the results from the client. If you profile your code, you will be able to prove if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. You lead me to run the profiler to check and actually found that the bulk of the issue is in the conversion from Dict to multi-dim Array.. I've added an expanded example, if you have any ideas?

Comment: What is the `dict` method?? You are calling `dict(dataPre)` but i can't find a method like that defined. Is that a private method? Note that in general, you do not need to convert to a dic to get the fields out of a Mongo result. The `rec` variable, which is the element in your for loop, will be of type `BSONObject`, and you can directly index into that `rec["info"][v1]["meas"][v2]["vals"]`

Comment: If I do that I get an error saying it's not possible to convert between a BSON object and float64. Same if I don't use dict and wrap the result in Float64()

Comment: I've fixed the issue you raised by removing the dict() and using Float64() or map(Float64,...) instead. No speed improvement unfortunately.

Comment: The main delay seems to be in entering data into the array `form_arr`. If there was a way to get data out of a multi-layered repeated BSON structure, that may help. i.e. avoiding loops doing something like `form_arr[:,:,:,i] = data["info"][1:100]["meas"][1:8]["vals"]`